# Rewrite both domain and path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect one specific url like:

```
www.example.com/test/ex.gif
```

to

```
static.example.com/ex.gif
```

How can i do this in .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the top of my head:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/test/ex.gif$ http://static.example.com/ex.gif [NC,R=301]
```

or to any file in test:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/test/(.*)$ http://static.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

> Corrected after advice from Mr. Berardi

Comment: Actually the example you have is wrong.  You don't want (.*) in front of the path, because then anything like /blah/blah/blah/text/ex.gif will also be caught.  You just want RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$ http://static.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301].  Notice that the "L" is also not necessary because a redirect automatically breaks out of the rewrite rules.

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem. I thought that ^ is the start of line anchor and if so I'm having a hard to time to see how ^/test/ could match. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) http://static.example.com/$1
```

Or this [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) directive:

```
Redirect /test/ http://static.example.com/
```