# Need to rewrite both the HTTP_HOST and the path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to be able to rewrite both the HTTP_HOST and the path at the same time working as:

```
 http://playground.emptycabinmedia.com/<category name>/<post name> to http://emptycabinmedia.com/<post name>
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366736/rewrite-both-domain-and-path) but didn't seem to work for me.  Here's what I have thus far in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^playground.emptycabinmedia.com/(.*)/(.*)$ emptycabinmedia.com/$2 [R=301]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a protocol like `http://` on the rewritten url, to show that you are not rewriting to a relative url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^playground.emptycabinmedia.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ http://emptycabinmedia.com/$2 [R=301]
```

Comment: @Larry I updated my answer.  Rewrite conditionally on the server's name.

Comment: Nope, not working either.  I think the rewrite in this case will just rewrite the SERVER_NAME right?

Comment: @Larry No, the rewrite will rewrite the url from `^/(.*)/(.*)$` to `http://emptycabinmedia.com/$2` under the condition that the `SERVER_NAME` is `playground.emptycabinmedia.com`. So if you visit `playground.emptycabinmedia.com/a/b` you should end up on `emptycabinmedia.com/b`.  If it's not working, then what is it doing, and is there anything in your logs?

Comment: Try using `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `%{SERVER_NAME}`

Comment: Thanks Gerben, thought of that myself - same result - not working.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. Here is what is showing on the logs when I navigate to: http://playground.emptycabinmedia.com/test/test ==> [31/May/2012:13:46:02 --0700] [playground.emptycabinmedia.com/sid#b81dcb08][rid#b861dc10/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/emptycabinmedia.com/subdomains/playground/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/emptycabinmedia.com/subdomains/playground/httpdocs/test/test -> test/test